# Uploading a picture to the server in the post body using Retrofit2

Tags: android, post, retrofit2

I use retrofit2 for android to upload pictures in the body of the Post request. My code works, but there's a nuance. I need to have only an image in the body of the request, but 2 additional lines are added in the body. it's the Content-Lenght: something, and one more. Here is an example of my code

An interface RequestService

```
@Multipart
@POST("photos")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadPhoto(
        @Query("ext") String ext,
        @Query("serial") int serial,
        @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

And the main body of request

```
RequestBody photoPart = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(file.getClass().getName()), file);

    MultipartBody.Part multiPartCn = MultipartBody.Part.create(photoPart);

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(APIUrlLink.getAPILink())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    RequestService requestService = retrofit.create(RequestService.class);

    Call<ResponseBody> call = requestService.uploadPhoto(str, ser, multiPartCn);
    call.enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            // something
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            // something
        }
    });
```

How can I make that the body of the POST request has only a picture without service information?

[There is the body on the server side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHdBc.png)

Comment: Please add to your question, what the additional content is, exactly. I assume that it is something that is required/defined by multipart requests.

Comment: I added the screen shoot on the text above. Yes, I suppose too. But how can I clean it? Please, need help

Comment: If you want to upload image with some parameters then you should pass it with `RequestBody` instead of other data types.

Answer (score 0):

When you send any other params along with the multipart you have to send them as RequestBody instead of String or Integer,

In your interface class replace as below,

```
@Multipart
@POST("photos")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadPhoto(
        @Part("ext") RequestBody ext,
        @Part("serial") RequestBody serial,
        @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

And in the java class

```
RequestBody str = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),str);
RequestBody ser=RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),String.valueOf(ser);
```

This should work. Let me know if it helps! 
Thanks

Comment: Thank for your answer. But I need send ext and serial like a params of the Post request and in the body only image

Comment: @АртемАртемов, look at my answer it will send Image and other parts inside one body and you can fetch all the image + data via creating POJO class(optionally) at the server side.

Answer (score 0):

you need to send your data in Multiparts, so first create RequestBody and set its type as Multipart_form.

```
  MultipartBody.Builder builder = new MultipartBody.Builder();
  builder.setType(MultipartBody.FORM);
```

Now add your image inside this body, and name that part whatever you want.

```
 RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), Imagefile);
 builder.addFormDataPart("ImagePartName", file.getName(), requestBody);
 MultipartBody requestBody = builder.build();
```

Send this Body inside Parameter of your API call, like this ->

```
 String ext = "whatecer String you want to put here";
 int serial = 132134; /* whatever serial number you want to put here*/

 //  Upload Images...
Api.uploadCropImage(requestBody,ext,serial,new Callback<BasicResponse>()
{
    @Override
    public void onResponse (Call < BasicResponse > call, Response < BasicResponse > response){
    if (response.body() != null && response.body().isSuccess()) {
       // Image Successfully uploaded.. Do something here
    } else {
       // Image not uploaded suceessfully.. Do something here        
    }
}

    @Override
    public void onFailure (Call < BasicResponse > call, Throwable t){
       // Error Occured Retry.. 
    }
});
```

this is how you define your api.

```
   public interface UploadCropImageApi {
        @POST(UPLOAD_FILE_TO_URL)
        Call<BasicResponse> uploadCropImage(
                @Header("ext") String ext,
                @Header("serial") int serial,
                @Body RequestBody requestBody);
    }
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. I'll try now and wiil give a feedback

Comment: there is an  error
@Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding

Comment: Remove Multipart annotation from API declaration, you can't use Body annotation alongside Multipart, and in my API Interface i haven't done that as well.

Comment: yes, sorry, it's my mistake. Thank for your answer. But it's not solves the situation, because in the body of the POST request there is service data, and I need to have only a picture

Comment: if you want both separately just send image inside request Body and text data inside Header. let me edit my answer.

Comment: builder.addFormDataPart("ImagePartName", file.getName(), requestBody); 
in the string you added the name of image and add it in the body. And retrofit put inside body Content-Lenght. I need, that to in the body not was nothing except image

Comment: @АртемАртемов, i didnot get your point, explain it in simplest terms in your usecase scenario. the ImagePartName can be any name, it's just to identify parts on server side.

Comment: my English is not good, so I apologize if I explain incorrect. On the server side they get my post request. They check params in request, if it's ok, they will get the body where I need to put image. In the body must be only image (encoded, of course), without any data (service data or not). If in the body there are some data (Content-Lenght, for example, like on the screen shoot) then on the server side can't be accepted image.

Comment: @АртемАртемов, you can pass these data of containing validation inside header and pass image as RequestBody. This is the same thing i am doing in my code as well. the only difference is I am using Spring as backend, but concept remains the same.

Comment: so, how can I send inside header Content-Lenght if it's added with okhttp library?

Comment: look at my code, i have made changes that will send your string inside header,you just need to pass whatever String you want and inside API interface just add Header Annotation with header-name.

Comment: maybe we don't understand each other. let me explain, pls. Do you see the screen shoot ?

Comment: Yes i can see that.

Comment: Do you see 2 strings on the top of screen shoot? I need them gone.

Comment: Answer Edited,check it out.

Comment: Please be clear on your question, what do u mean by service information exists? You says that u want to send data alongside images, but separate to request Body and the code does the same as you want. Now you can modify the code as per your preference. This community is not responsible for giving out whole code, but just to give you example codes.

Comment: yes, I know, thank you so much for your time. As I sad I need send image in the body of POST request. The body must have no any information, besides image. But when I send request I have in the body 2 strings like on the screen shot

Comment: @АртемАртемов I am facing the same problem, were you able to find the fix for this problem, if yes please let me know, Thanks in advance

Comment: @XavitojCheema really? on the 1C server?

Comment: Sorry, I had to upload a file to S3 with the PUT call and I was by mistake using Multipart with PUT call. I solved my problem by removing @Mulitpart tag from the api call.

Answer (score 0):

I think the body looks as it is supposed to, following multipart encoding.

You just need a proper backend to get the actual data out of the request again -- it's been a while since I did this, but in Java this should be possible using ServletRequest or similar. Depends on what you use for the backend.

From the client (Android) perspective, I think it is perfectly correct.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I have no access to the server side, I have only information about POST request, params of this and that the body must content only an image without service information (like on the srcreen shoot). Thanks

Comment: Hm. In that case you can perhaps do the Base64 encoding of the image yourself and then send that encoded data as a String body. However the string might become pretty huge, so normally you would have an OutputStream that is connected the Request to write into, but with Retrofit I think that's too low level.

Comment: yes, I saw the okhttp library sourse code, I saw where it's added the strings and I want to know, can I send POST body request with only image in the body. Maybe there's another way in the retrofit library

Comment: @Ridcully, base64 encoding can work, but it won't be as efficient as Multipart.

Comment: @JayDangar It's just a suggestion, since backend seems not to work with Multipart.

Comment: @Ridcully, what kind of backend is he using? is it spring?

Comment: @JayDangar ooh, it's not the spring. It's 1C, maybe you know

Comment: no I don't have idea of 1C, but you can still get the data via request part with name attribute as partName that you sent via requestBody.